# Angular2 services dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

When `AuthService => login` is called, the logger correctly appends `Foo!` in the browser console but 
when `ErroHandler => handleError` is called, the instance of the logger is always undefined (except in the constructor of the class). I expected to see `Bar!` also beeing appended in the browser console.
Can anyone explain me this behaviour?

Reference: https://embed.plnkr.co/cKwT5R39IL1TTJBRvZyY/

Comment: What did make you think that it is not correctly injected? Please, provide the details that explain the problem in the question itself. To my knowledge, it is not allowed to post plunker link without relevant code (there's a guard against this in SO editor for this, but it was bypassed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with dependency injection. If DI problem occurs, this results in error message from compiler.

This happens because `errorHandler.handleError` method is passed as a callback here:

```
.catch(this.errorHandler.handleError);
```

and isn't bound correctly to the context.

This is a typical mistake. Unless it is known that object method was bound on object construction (this is a good habit for methods that are supposed to be used as callbacks by design), it always should be like

```
.catch(err => this.errorHandler.handleError(err));
```